# Django, adding multiple databases miscofigured my settings

Tags: python, django

I had a fully working test project which used only one database (Django 1.8 + PostgreSQL 9.1). Then, I was asked to add multiple databases. I dropped the one database I was using and created 3 new ones. I modified settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'core',
        'USER': 'chris',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'db1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'USER': 'chris',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        },
    'db2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db2',
        'USER': 'chris',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = 'default'
```

*(using automatic database routing and only one models.py)*

When I try to make my first migrations I now get this:

`django-admin.py makemigrations --database=db1`

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

But then I do this:

```
(testproject) chris@ubuntu-pc ~/D/w/testproject> python manage.py shell
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
'default'
>>> settings.configure()
RuntimeError: Settings already configured.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *exactly* did you run to create the migrations?

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `manage.py` inside the project instead of `django-admin.py`:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

You don't need to pass database names to `makemigrations`. But you do need to migrate each database separately while migrating.

```
python manage.py migrate --database=db1
```